# How does python read the content of txt file and save it in excel

Tags: python, excel

in one folder, there are two files a.txt   b.txt

a.txt has data,
a111
a222
a333

b.txt has data,
b111
b222
b333

I want their data to save into the excel file one column

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. I recommend you google openpyxl and go through some examples that you find.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Read txt files is very easy in python, what problem did you find?. To write a excel file, use XlsxWriter.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = "your.xlsx")
ws = wb.activewith 
row1 = 1
open("demo.txt") as file:
for item in file:
    ws.cell(row=row1, column=1).value = item
    row1 = row1 + 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).